# Redirecting Subdomain to an IP Without www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I trying for hours and almost get mad. I want to redirect my sub.example.com to a file on remote server file.

So I want to redirect my subdomains (with www/without www) to x.x.x.x/example/photo.jpg

Everything works fine for www.sub.example.com. It perfectly redirects to x.x.x.x/example.
When it comes to sub.example.com, I have 404.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/x\.x\.x\.x\/example/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteCond's are implicitly "AND"ed together, that means you will never get an %{HTTP_HOST} that is both "sub.example.com" and "www.sub.example.com" at the same time, thus the RewriteRule will never get used. You can add an `[OR]` after the first one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
```

So that either RewriteCond can be fulfilled and the Rule will get used, or just use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.example\.com$
```

Which is essentially saying the "www." can be optional in the match.

Answer (score 0):

[cliknfind website](http://www.cliknfind.com)

use this code RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]